# Taking only last value of Object

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to implement Google Graph but What is the wrong in this code, it is taking last value of object.

```
var colEvn = ["AAA","BBB","CCC"];

var viewObj = new Object();

    var func = function viewFunc(dt, row) {
        return (dt.getValue(row, 1) == colEvn[j]) ? dt.getValue(row, 2) : null;
    }
    var viewObj = new Object();

    for (var j = 0, m = colEvn.length; j < m; j++) {
        viewObj.type = 'number';
        viewObj.label = colEvn[j];
        viewObj.calc = func
     }


    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, viewObj]);
```

The expected result should be like this :

```
{
        type: 'number',
        label: 'AAA',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            return (dt.getValue(row, 1) == 'AAA') ? dt.getValue(row, 2) : null;
        }
    }, {
        type: 'number',
        label: 'BBB',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            return (dt.getValue(row, 1) == 'BBB') ? dt.getValue(row, 2) : null;
        }
    }, {
        type: 'number',
        label: 'CCC',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            return (dt.getValue(row, 1) == 'CCC') ? dt.getValue(row, 2) : null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I moved my answer, check it out and let me know about the alerts.

Answer (score 1):

The iteration is overwriting the same object every time, and it seems like an array of objects should be passed visualization API.

Reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView_setColumns), it also seems like an object should be passed with the index of the column to the `setColumns` function, so you probably have to do that in the loop as well

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

for (var j = 0, m = colEvn.length; j < m; j++) {
    var viewObj = {
        type:  'number',
        label: colEvn[j],
        calc:  func
    };
    view.setColumns([j, viewObj]);
 }
```

Comment: But where is here func? And add this var func = function viewFunc(dt, row) {
        return (dt.getValue(row, 1) == colEvn[j]) ? dt.getValue(row, 2) : null;
    }

Comment: But it is still giving me the last value of object

Comment: adeneo what about func? I think the problem inside this function can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

ok then, first point is you can't create a single function for all your columns, I have changed it like:

```
var colEvn = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"];
var columns = [0];
for (var j = 0, m = colEvn.length; j < m; j++) {
    var viewObj = {};
    viewObj.type = 'number';
    viewObj.label = colEvn[j];
    viewObj.calc = function viewFunc(dt, row) {
        alert("column label : " + viewFunc._colEvn);
        return (dt.getValue(row, 1) == viewFunc._colEvn) ? dt.getValue(row, 2) : null;
    };
    viewObj.calc._colEvn = colEvn[j];
    columns.push(viewObj);
}

var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns(columns);
```

Let me know, if the `alerts` execute in your code and what they show.

Comment: I trie this code it alerts 7 or 8 times and every time it shows me "column label : AA" or "column label : BB" but in the graph it takes only last one in this case only "BB", "AA" is missing but in alert it is displaying